# Extend a scss class and keep everything the same except add !important

Tags: css, sass, styles

If I have this class in an .scss file:

```
.aClass {
    min-height: 500px;
    // ... more css properties
}
```

I'd like to create another class that inherits from aClass and makes the fields !important.
I know I can inherit doing this:

```
.bClass {
    @extend .aClass
}
```

But how can I make the fields from .aClass marked as `!important` in .bClass?

Comment: you want to override the .bClass css with .aClass css or do you want to apply !importnat to .aClass property?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by using a [mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) with an [@each](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) loop in Sass. Here's an example:

```
@mixin myMixin($str){
  $prop : (
    color:red,
    border:1px solid red,
    position:relative
  );
  @each $key, $value in $prop {
    #{$key}: #{$value} #{$str};
  }
}
.test-a {
    @include myMixin(!important);
}
.test-b {
  @include myMixin('');
}
```

In this example, I'm applying !important as the `#{$str}` in the mixin. This makes `.test-a` apply `!important` to all properties, and adding the empty string to .test-b ensures `!important` is not added.